# Windows 10 System Repair Disc from Another PC

Tags: windows-10, partition-recovery, system-recovery

Is the "*system repair disc*" created via "*Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Backup and Restore (Windows 7)*" good for that PC only, or is it interchangeable between any PCs running Windows 10?

Comment: Umm... What good is a Windows 7 repair disc on a system running Windows 10? Windows 7/8 use an OEM version of the OS for specific PC's, in most cases any Dell Windows 7/8 disc can be used on any Dell PC that originally had that version of Windows. Windows 10 is a similar but more generic, you can use the OEM version from that hardware or the Microsoft version to restore it. A "repair disk" is actually different and you can't reinstall from it to as different machine, depending on the specific issue.

Comment: @acejavelin, see "answer" below. Windows 10 dialog for "Backup and restore (Windows 7)"

Comment: Win7 repair disc is only good for W7 systems.

Answer (score 0):

There are different types of backups that may be made from the *Backup and Restore (Windows **7**)* dialog in Windows **10**. (Yes, it does seem an odd title for v. 10 - it's a hint, perhaps, that this is deprecated?)

- `Backup or restore your files`: This saves your personal data, but *not* operating system (OS) files. [These files *can* be restored to another machine](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17127/windows-back-up-restore), assuming they're not encrypted.
- `Create a system repair disc`: This makes an image of OS files, but *not* data. [These images are probably *not* portable.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance-winpc/windows-10-recovery-disk-made-from-another/8bede80e-7804-4b65-a778-d02f190fd0de) During the original installation, drivers *specific to that PC* were downloaded and installed. It is *possible* that identical make and model machines with identical OS would have the same drivers, but manufacturers change hardware during production runs of a model, so that is not certain.

Another issue is that Microsoft identifies a PC by its hardware (including things such as HDD and CPU serial numbers), as well as license key. Restoring on different hardware *might* later require authentication, if license information was lost.

[image: Backup and Restore dlg]

So it might be worth a try, if you don't have a recent *disk* image, e.g. that made by third-party tools such as [Macrium Reflect](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) and [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/). If it fails, there are other options.

- Download [Create Windows 10 installation media](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), put it on USB or DVD, and then [Perform a Repair Upgrade Using the Windows 10 ISO file](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install-winpc/how-to-perform-a-repair-upgrade-using-the-windows/35160fbe-9352-4e70-9887-f40096ec3085). This *may* save your current data and programs.
- If that fails, use the installation media above for a full installation.
- If none of these meet your needs, try a free alternative OS such as [Ubuntu Linux](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install-winpc/how-to-perform-a-repair-upgrade-using-the-windows/35160fbe-9352-4e70-9887-f40096ec3085).